Sprite lit shaders are going black after exporting to android
I am making a 2d unity game and everything works fine in the editor and game view. But when I export it for android and open it on my phone through google play all the sprites turn black (The water doesn’t because it is unlit). Is there a setting in player settings or something like that?
Here are some screen shots (sorry it only lets me post one screen shot):
First pic is the scene view second is on my phone
I have looked at the player settings, deleted all quality settings expect one (so that my phone wasn't switching to a different quality setting), and I have tested to make sure the like is on.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
